# Does the "odo odo" in this question mean fearful?

Tags: meaning, definitions

it is my first time posting here and I have very little experience with Japanese language. Recently, a Japanese user in this game I play posted on my wall: どうもフレンド申請はおどおど受け可能ですか？ Does "odo odo" mean fearful in this context? I can't help but think I did something wrong to scare the other person...anyway, thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: Expressions like おどおど受け are occasionally used among [*yaoi*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaoi_fandom) fans, but the game you play is not related to this genre, right?

Comment: No, it is an fantasy RPG. What does it mean in the yaoi context?

Comment: Something like "timid bottom (character type)"; please read the last paragraph of the "Fan preferences" section.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a native speaker of Japanese and also am a gamer, and I have to say this sentence is ungrammatical and hard to interpret, unless this おどおど受け (literally "timid reception") has some special meaning in the game you play.

It may be some terrible typo, or maybe it was originally an emoji ([like these](http://emojibank.com/#!%E3%81%8A%E3%81%A9%E3%81%8A%E3%81%A9)) and then was turned into hiragana for some reason.

Even if the person who wrote this actually intended to write おどおど, you don't have to worry too much. Some people can be おどおど (timid) to anyone whom they don't know well.